# Can't use fetch inside yield call in redux saga

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga, yield

I am making an api call and based on the response, I have to update the state.
This is what I am doing.

```
function* testEndpointConnectivity(action){
    const { testConnectivityUri, rowItem } = action.payload
    const res=  yield call( fetch(testConnectivityUri).then(response => {
        //something here
        })
    )
   
   yield put({type: SOME_ACTION});
   
}
```

But this doesn't work. I get the error

```
 Error: call: argument fn is undefined
```

At first I tried putting the *yield put* in the *catch* and *then* of the response, but stackoverflow told me to use *yield call*.

Please help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not correct

if you check [doc](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/) you will see the first argument it's function and then you can send arguments:

> call(fn, ...args)

So, in your example correct variant must look like:

```
function* testEndpointConnectivity(action) {
    const { testConnectivityUri, rowItem } = action.payload;
    const response = yield call(fetch, testConnectivityUri);
    // and in generator you can wait your answer, you dont need use .then
    console.log("response", response);

    yield put({ type: SOME_ACTION });

}

 // this error mean, first argument in call function must be fetch
 Error: call: argument fn is undefined
```

Comment: I tried it, but was getting another error `TypeError: Object(...)(...).then is not a function`

Comment: updated my code with fixed syntax errors @ParthSingh

Comment: This saved my life. Thanks a ton.